# Nginx merge two locations

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I've split up most of my config files so it looks like this (simplified)

**example.conf**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    #stuff......    

    #########
    # Base WordPress configuration, setup php and everything
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/wordpress.conf;

}
```

**wordpress.conf**

```
#stuff......
location / {
    try_files /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index-https.html /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php ;
}
#stuff......
```

So far so good. Now I want to secure only example.com with http-auth

So I add to the `example.conf` the following;

```
    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

But then I get the error;

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/snippets/wordpress.conf:53
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What is the best way to enable http-auth on this domain only?
I could create an alternative `wordpress.conf` but that would defeat the idea of splitting up configs.

Comment: You should place the `auth_basic` directives in the `server` block if you want the entire site at `example.com` protected - which will also solve the duplicate `location` problem.

Comment: Yes, that Works. Thanks. But I'm still curious what would be the best way to handle a _merge_ in general.